# How to fix this Minecraft 1.7.10 server error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having a problem with this one error when I try to log onto a server, and I've looked for answers but haven't found any. What causes the error and how to fix it?

> Internal Exception: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Sometimes this happens when you try to login into a server with a different MC version than you, or when one side has mods/resource packs and the other not.

Comment: Is this a server that you host?

Comment: This could be anything... bad connection, server issues (even a server restart/shutdown would cause this), missing resources,  buggy plugins or mods, etc  pp. To narrow it down to the real issue you should check your logs and/or mods & resource packs first (or even better: use a clean minecraft installation), then try another server.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error means that something triggered a bug in the remote host. This could be caused by a poor connection between you and the host, the server could have actually dropped your connection, or you could be sending incorrect information to the server, causing a bug. Try switching your version to the one that the server works best on.